# How can I see the name of a process owner from the OSX prompt?

Tags: macos, process

If I run `ps -ef` in the OSX terminal, the list of processes includes the UID - the numerical user id of the process owner. How can I see the name of the process owner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `-j` flag. For example, `ps -j`, or combined with other flags, like `ps -efj`.

The man page (`man ps`) describes the `-j` flag like this:

> Print information associated with the following keywords: **user**, pid,
>   ppid, pgid, sess, jobc, state, tt, time, and command.

The "user" part is the user name.

Comment: `ef` is optional – `j` also works without.

Comment: @DanielBeck - answer updated to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution: use `ps -ej`.

General solution: use `ps -eo user,pid,tty,command`.

The `ps` command lets you control what information (what columns) is displayed using the `-o` option, e.g.

```
ps -o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,command
```

displays *username, PID, recent CPU and memory usage and command* for each process that is shown.

The `-j` option displays *user, pid, parent pid, process gid, session, job control count, state, control terminal name, accumulated CPU time, and command with arguments*.

The `-f` option displays *uid, pid, parent pid, recent CPU usage, process start time, controling tty, elapsed CPU usage, and the associated command*. Hence, there's probably no need to keep `-f` with `-j` or `-o`.

See [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html) for details.